# Python C-Extensions with array of integers argument

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a simple C++ file that I want to export into Python via a C-extension. I compile my .cc file and create a shared library, which I then call in Python using CDLL from ctypes. However, I am struggling to pass in a Python list correctly when I call the library function and it does not return correctly. Where am I going wrong?

```
// test.cc
    
extern "C" {

    int call_my_routine(int *array) {

        int i;
        int count = 0;
        for(i=0; array[i]!='\0'; i++)
        {
            count++;
        }
    return count;

    }
}


// test.py
from ctypes import CDLL, c_int

so_file = "./libtest.so"

my_function = CDLL(so_file)

py_list = [2,3,5,7,4,12,21,49]
array = (c_int * len(py_list))(*py_list)

print(my_function.call_my_routine(array))
```

The correct output should be 8, but is instead returning 17.

I compile the shared lib with

```
g++ -I ./inc -fpic -c test.cc -o test.o

g++ -shared -o libtest.so test.o
```

Disclosure, I am not a C programmer.

Comment: Will also mention I am on Mac M1 arm64.

Comment: Why are you looking for a null terminator in an array that's not null terminated?

Comment: @user2357112 That could be it, I don't really know how to pass the array into C and get its length. I tried pointer arithmetic `*(&array + 1) - array;` and that didn't return the correct length either. This is a thin C-wrapper between a C++ application and Python. Whilst I am familiar enough with std::vectors, (which I ultimately want to use), I don't know how to compile Python->C++ without C layer.

Comment: For example, having `call_my_routine` return `sizeof(*array)/sizeof(array[0]);` instead gives the answer of 1 in Python.

Comment: Arrays don't store their length. The interface you have designed for `call_my_routine` does not provide the routine with the length information it needs.

Comment: You might want to look into options like [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), since it seems you're much more comfortable with C++ than C.